# Substring Maximum Length

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, substring, asp.net-4.5

I have strings of length greater than 150 characters. I want to delete the first 17 characters and leave the rest. I am using the Substring method in ASP.net 4.5 but I get the error message at str0: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException".

```
 public static string extract(string dirinfo)
 {
      Int32 lensub = Convert.ToInt32(dirinfo.Length);
      string str0 = dirinfo.Substring(17, lensub);
      return str0;
 }
```

Comment: That's because `Substring(17, lensub)` means start at the 17th character and then move forward the same number of spaces as the full length of the string. Obviously 17 characters from the end you're now "Out of range". Try `Substring(17, lensub - 17);`

Answer (score 6):

You should remove the constant 17 from the len calculated

```
 public static string extract(string dirinfo)
 {
      Int32 lensub = Convert.ToInt32(dirinfo.Length);
      string str0 = dirinfo.Substring(17, lensub-17);
      return str0;
 }
```

Otherwise the required number of chars to return is more than the remaining length of the string

Of course, (giving credit to the [answer from Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34879634/1197518)) you could simplify your method to

```
 public static string extract(string dirinfo)
 {
      return (dirinfo.Length > 17 ? dirinfo.Substring(17) : "");
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Substring(int, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload takes length as a second parameter that you want to the *rest* as you said, not the complete string length.

If your string length is 150, `dirinfo.Substring(17, 150)` means;

> Starts with 17 as a position ant takes 150 character **after** it.

Which means, your string needs `167` character *at least* but it does not. That's why you get `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Just use [`Substring(int)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as;

```
string str0 = dirinfo.Substring(17);
```

which is described;

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
>   specified character position **and continues to the end of the string**.

By the way, `Length` is *already* `int`, you don't need to parse it.

Comment: @Steve But you were 33 second faster :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string str0 = dirinfo.Substring(17, lensub-17);
return str0;
```

Comment: string str0 = dirinfo.Substring(17, lensub-17);
return str0;

Answer (score 0):

> I want to **delete** the first **17 characters** and leave the rest.

Then do exactly what you want

```
string str0 = dirinfo.Remove(0, 17);
```

Reference: [String.Remove Method (Int32, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public string Remove(int startIndex, int count)
```

> Returns a new string in which a **specified number of characters** in the current instance beginning at a specified position have been **deleted**.